# Smallest k X l Grid That Guarantees to Find Four Monochromatic Points

Tags: python, algorithm

Suppose each point in Z X Z is colored with one of n given colors.

Find the Smallest k and l such that in any k x l grid one is guaranteed to find four monochromatic points that are vertices of a rectangle.

---

For the case of n=1, smallest (k,l) would be obviously (2,2)

For the case of n=2, I had found 4 X 4 colored grid which still not making any monochromatic rectangle :

$baba\aabb\abaa\bbab
$

Is there any computational way to make it automatically searched?

I need your advice

(I only knows python for reference)

Comment: "monochromatic points"? What is `n`?

Comment: monochromatic means every vertices shares same color, additionally n refer to the n given colors

Comment: Please have a look at my answer and comment if you like. @Beverlie

Answer (score 0):

The smallest k and l (following L to distinguish from 1) would be such that the equation

```
k * L >= (k + L) * n
```

is satisfied. To explain that please consider a grid (k,L) into which we want to place as many pixels of the same color, say red, as possible. As soon as `k + L - 1` pixels have been placed there's no room left to add another one without becoming the vertex of a rectangle.

[image: grid]

So as soon as we count `k + L` pixels of the same color in grid (k,L) it's safe to say that at least one such a vertex list will be present.

Now we consider two colors arbitrarily arranged inside the grid. For any arrangement we can say that at least `k * L / 2` pixels of the *most* used color will be present. So it is safe to assume that, if `k * L / 2` is greater or equal to `k + L`, at least one such a rectangle can be found among the most used color.

For 3 colors we consider `k * L / 3` and so on, which leads to the formula `k * L / n >= k + L` for n colors.